# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError using bartMachine package in R

Tags: r, bayesian, java

I ran a BART model with 11000 samples and 20 features(half of them are categorical variable). My mac has 8G ram. At first, I set memory to 5000 MB via function set_bart_machine_memory(5000).

Then I can fit a model through the function bartMachine one time. If I want to run another model then the R returns a error like this:

```
 Exception in thread "pool-10-thread-1" Exception in thread "pool-10-thread-3"
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 Exception in thread "pool-10-thread-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 Exception in thread "pool-10-thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 Error in .jcall(bart_machine$java_bart_machine, "Z", "isDestroyed") :
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I think that having two bartMachine object in memory may not be a good idea, so I just kill the first model through function destroy_bart_machine(), then the second model is OK to run.

The main problem is on bartMachineCV(). There are about 20 model to fit in default, and the memory error like the one above hits me when R is running the bart model with second set of parameter setting (that is : bartMachine CV try: k: 2 nu, q: 3, 0.9 m: 200 ).

I'm not familiar to JAVA, is there some way to run bartMachineCV() on a 8GB RAM computer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of the bartMachine package. Make sure you download the new version and pay attention the message that appears after you initialize the library:

```
> library(bartMachine)
...
Welcome to bartMachine v1.2.0! You have 0.48GB memory available.
```

If you see a low amount of RAM on the message, something is wrong with your JVM setup. 64-bit JVM is a must. Use

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx2500m")
```

before calling `library(bartMachine)` to attempt to set more.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run a 64-bit Java JVM; the 32-bit JVM only gives you ~1.8GB max heap.  I'd recommend that you use JDK 7 or higher; that's production for Oracle these days.

Once you have that, you can set JVM memory settings like this:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

You'll want to set `-Xmx=1024M` or something like that.